# A simple way of accommodating multiple bibliographies

Tags: bibliographies, subdividing

I'd like to accommodate several bibliographies in a document. I am aware of packages like `multibib`, `multibbl` and `bibtopic` to achieve this, but I'd prefer a simple quick-and-dirty solution for a specific purpose.

I have a main bibliography which I build with `bibtex`. In addition, in another part of the document I want to put an extra little bibliography. The following MWE tells you what I want to achieve:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report} 

\begin{document}

\section{Further Reading}

\subsection*{Journal Papers}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem[Art1]{art1}    J. Doe, ``Fancy title'', {\em {IEEE} Transactions on Signal Processing}, 2010
\bibitem[Art2]{art2}    J. Williams, ``Another title'', {\em {IEEE} Transactions on Magnetics}, 2011
\end{thebibliography}

\subsection*{Conference Papers}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem[Art3]{art3}    A. Clifford, ``Yet another one'', {\em {IEEE} Transactions on Automatic Control}, 2013
\bibitem[Art4]{art4}    B. Jefferson, ``Last one'', {\em {IEEE} Transactions on Information Systems}, 2008
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that my thesis template (in the above example, I have chosen the `report` documentclass as an equivalent) has its own way of putting bibliographies on different pages.

How can I override this behavior locally and avoid a page break?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `report` class uses `\chapter*` to print the bibliography header, while the `article` class uses `\section*`.

A possible solution is to use the `xpatch` package (i.e., include `\usepackage{xpatch}`) to replace `\chapter*` with `\section*` in the definition of `\thebibliography` (this is the command executed by `\begin{thebibliography}`

The required modification is

```
\xpatchcmd{\thebibliography}{\chapter*}{\section*}{}{}
```

Here is the outcome

[image]

Please notice that I have replaced `\section*{Conference Papers}` with `\subsection*{Conference Papers}` for consistency with the previous one.

A further improvement would be to remove the `\section` entries and replace them with

```
\renewcommnad{\bibname}{Journal Articles}
```

for the first and

```
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Conference Papers}
```

for the second.

Comment: Thanks. I've corrected `\section*` to `\subsection*` in my post.

Comment: A minor comment though: This solution still produces two entries in my table of content, labelled as "References". Ideally I would be able to suppress those too.

Comment: @jens I cannot reproduce with the MWE you provided. Do you use additional packages (i.e., `tocbibind`)?

Answer (score 1):

You might also consider getting rid of the sectioning that is done by `\begin{thebibliography}` and just using your own labels as the sections themselves.  This appears cleaner to me.

[image: example]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report} 

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\thebibliography}{\chapter*{\bibname}}{}{}{} % Remove sectioning for bibliography entirely

\begin{document}

\section{Further Reading}

\subsection*{Journal Papers} % Create own sections

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem[Art1]{art1}    J. Doe, ``Fancy title'', {\em {IEEE} Transactions on Signal Processing}, 2010
\bibitem[Art2]{art2}    J. Williams, ``Another title'', {\em {IEEE} Transactions on Magnetics}, 2011
\end{thebibliography}

\subsection*{Conference Papers} % Create own sections

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem[Art3]{art3}    A. Clifford, ``Yet another one'', {\em {IEEE} Transactions on Automatic Control}, 2013
\bibitem[Art4]{art4}    B. Jefferson, ``Last one'', {\em {IEEE} Transactions on Information Systems}, 2008
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Of course, keep in mind that `biblatex` also does an excellent job of this sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks cslstr, the result of your solution seems equivalent to that of Guido. I had to accept one answer.